# Difference between "...come in second behind..."and "...come second behind..."

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

> Who would **come in** second behind Donald Trump?

Does

> Who would **come** second behind Donald Trump?

have the same meaning?

I am confused.

Is "come in" a phrasal verb in the above sentence?

or

Is "in second behind" a phrasal preposition in the above sentence?

Comment: *come in = place or ranking in a competition.* Yes, it's a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [***come in***](https://www.google.com/search?q=come+in&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is a phrasal verb:

> 2) finish a race in a specified position. "the favorite *came in* first"

So the best way to say this would be:

> Who would **come in** second behind Donald Trump?

While people informally might say:

> Who would **come** second behind Donald Trump?

this is a matter of omitting "in". In both phrases, "second" is still an adverb, and the prepositional phrase is "behind Donald Trump".